# call function in view

Tags: codeigniter, function, call

i wanna ask something about codeigniter

here is the view

```
<input class="mws-textinput" name="div_id" type="text" readonly="readonly">
<input class="mws-textinput" name="div_name" type="text" readonly="readonly">
<input id="mws-jui-dialog-mdl-btn" class="mws-button blue small" type="button" value="Show Modal Dialog">
<div id="mws-jui-dialog">
     <p><? (**i wanna call the function here**) ?></p>
</div>
```

here is the function in controller

```
function dialog(){
        $query = mysql_query('select * from tbl_divisi');
        while($isi=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            echo '<a href="E:/web/intranet.net/application/views/user/tabel.php" onclick="setParent(\'$isi[div_id]\',\'$isi[div_name]\')"></a>';
        }
    }
```

what should i do?

Comment: if you insist to call a function in a view you can create a helper and do what ever you want

Answer (score 2):

There is two way either you can define this method in model and then call the method of that model in your view file or you can fetch all these values from controller. Here is the detail of how to use model in ci. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: I think calling model functions directly in view is bad practice. Controller should pass the data to the view.